# Unit testing RxJava

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am developing a unit test in Android to test my `RxJava2` code that interacts with `Socket.IO`. The code works well when I run from `MainActivity()`. In unit test I am using below code to test `Observable`:

```
ObservableFactory.sharedInstance.connectionStatusObservable.blockingForEach(connectionStatus -> {
    System.out.println(connectionStatus.getStatus());
});
```

The expected output is this:

```
Connecting
Connected
```

But it actually throws `NullPointerException` in `EventThread` after showing `Connecting` state:

```
Connecting
Jan 29, 2018 6:57:15 PM io.socket.thread.EventThread$2 run
SEVERE: Task threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:21)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:16)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:539)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:36)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:335)
    at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:126)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.access$700(Polling.java:18)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:127)
    at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:241)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:135)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:102)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:125)
    at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Exception in thread "EventThread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:21)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.HandshakeData.<init>(HandshakeData.java:16)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:539)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:36)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:335)
    at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:126)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.access$700(Polling.java:18)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:127)
    at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:241)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:135)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:102)
    at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:125)
    at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have also tried to use `TrampolineScheduler` as a rule in the beginning of test:

```
@Rule
public TrampolineSchedulerRule trampolineSchedulerRule = new TrampolineSchedulerRule();
```

But still I am receiving above error message. If I run the following test then it works well:

```
ConnectionStatus status = ObservableFactory.sharedInstance.connectionStatusObservable.blockingFirst();
assertTrue(status.getStatus() == ConnectionStatus.Status.Connecting);
```

**The problem is with `Connected` state where it successfully establish the connection with `Socket.IO` but somehow unit test is throwing error on it even if it works well in `MainActivity()`.**

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When unit testing RxJava observer chains, you often run into difficulties with the schedulers. The most common problem is introducing a deadlock where the test is waiting for results that will never arrive because it is blocking on the same thread that the result is being produced on. When testing network or operating system services, you will often run afoul of the asynchronous code embedded in the service. In your case, the trampoline scheduler is causing a variable to be used that has not actually been set yet because the network operation has not completed.

You will need to get away from the trampoline scheduler (I understand that it is not really supported in RxJava2), and use a specific scheduler, either `Schedulers.io()` or `Schedulers.computation()`.

The next part is to use a `TestSubscriber()` to actually check that the observer chain did its job.

```
Observable<ConnectionStatus> obs = 
  ObservableFactory.sharedInstance.connectionStatusObservable
  .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io() );
TestSubscriber ts = obs.test();
ts.awaitTerminalEvent();
ts.assertCompleted();
ts.assertValues( Connecting, Connected );
```

Comment: How are your initializing your connection? The stack trace shows that a packet was received, and something is throwing the NPE after that.